# How to access result and volume of WindowsServerBackup via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I want to check automatically the latest WindowsServerBackup result via PowerShell on Windows Server 2012/2012 R2.

It's not only "success" or "failure" but "backed-up volume" and "error message", too. So I tried using the following ways but I can't get the above informations.

1. `Get-WB*`  is not enough that I want to do.
2. I can't find WMI object around WindowsServerBackup.
3. `Get-Eventlog` can't access about Backup (Application and Service Log/Microsoft/Windows/Backup)

Did I miss some right way? What should I do?

(Sorry. I'm not good at English.)

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://serverfault.com/. It is a little bit off-topic here.

Comment: I'm so greatful for that,  Tomalak.

Comment: have a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/593530/server-2012r2-cannot-add-pssnapin-windows-serverbackup#593531

Comment: Cross-link to the [same question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/898356/906).